# How to @import .css file as a .scss file in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I am using gulp as a task runner which merge and minifying `scss` files for me. In this case if I try to import a regular `CSS` file, it will compile to a css `import` statement as below:

```css
/* style.scss */
@import "../../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css";

/* style.css */
@import url(../../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css);
```

So how to import that regular css file, to have a **compiled** version of that in the `style.css` instead of just `css @import` statement?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply do this:

```css
/* style.scss */
@import "../../bower_components/animate.css/animate";
```

Just don't write file extension, Import the file without the extension, the compiler will put the file content in `style.css` instead of putting `@import` rule.

Comment: Works like charm.

Comment: I also had to rename my file from .min.css to .css to make it work .. idk why